# MySQL 5.7 Multi Master Multi Source Replication issues after mysqld restart

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, innodb

I've a multi master & multi source replication setup working perfectly fine.

M1 -> M2 || 
M1 -> M3

M2 -> M1 ||
M2 -> M3

M3 -> M1 ||
M3 -> M2

As soon as I restart mysqld on M2 **I'm missing a channel**. And therfor the setup is broken. This is really weird. master_info_repository is set to table and SHOW SLAVE STATUS shows 2 lines & 2 channels BEFORE I do restart mysqld. After restart there's only 1 channel left.

There are no log entries in the error log that may hint to something weird at all.

MySQL Version 5.7.11

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, here what I did to solve this:

1. Enabled relay_log_recovery on `my.cnf`
2. flushed logs (`FLUSH LOGS` command).
3. Stopped mysqld service
4. moved all the relay logs and indexes out form the datadir
5. started mysqld service

The problem was that the relay log was inconsistent, and after those steps above my multi source replication worked even after a database restart.